# AppsScript - Range not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to update one script on Google Sheet to delete a specific array.
At the moment it deletes everything.

It seems pretty simple but I am not familiar yet with the syntax.

Can you help to correct this code:

```
  var destSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);
  var destSheet = destSpreadSheet.setActiveSheet(destSpreadSheet.getSheetByName(destinationSheet));
  destSheet.clearContents(); 
  destSheet.getRange(4, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

To ensure that not the full sheet is cleared, but only the range A4 to M

Possible?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `AppsScript - Range not a fonction` and `At the moment it deletes everything.` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of it? Although, unfortunately, I cannot understand this. But, about `To ensure that not the full sheet is cleared, but only the range A4 to M`, in this case, how about `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("### sheet name ###").getRange("A4:M").clearContent()`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Thank you, this works! ;)`, I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, I flagged it as a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48643317